# app shows unknown publisher when launched for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, installshield

I built app through visual studio. But when I launch app User Account Control shows Publisher: Unknown. I built it using VS2013. Where is the option I change publisher name or add sign file. I didn't sign tab in properties. Also I added my app in control panel but it is displayed as "my_app (32-bit)". Is there way to get rid of 32-bit, so display name will only show my_app. I gave path in registry to show in control panel.

Comment: To prove who you are in the UAC dialog, you have to buy a certificate from Verilog et al so your user doesn't just have to take *your* word for it.  You probably used the wrong registry key, nobody can see you do it.

Comment: I have certificate but I don't know the option in Visual Studio to apply it.